# Given dates every minute, extract every two

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a table like the following:

```
 ID     Date                    Value
 1      2018-04-29 14:51:01     0.1
 2      2018-04-29 14:51:01     0.21
 3      2018-04-29 14:51:01     0.123
 2      2018-04-29 14:52:01     5.7
 3      2018-04-29 14:52:01     1.2
 1      2018-04-29 14:52:01     5.9
 1      2018-04-29 14:53:01     1.23
 3      2018-04-29 14:53:01     7.9
 2      2018-04-29 14:53:01     1.68
 1      2018-04-29 14:54:01     0.01
 2      2018-04-29 14:54:01     0.068
 3      2018-04-29 14:54:01     0.2686
 2      2018-04-29 14:55:01     2.3
 3      2018-04-29 14:55:01     3.4
 1      2018-04-29 14:55:01     5.7
 1      2018-04-29 14:56:01     102.357
 3      2018-04-29 14:56:01     12.36
 2      2018-04-29 14:56:01     123.47
 1      2018-04-29 14:57:01     12379.42
 2      2018-04-29 14:57:01     1230.1
 3      2018-04-29 14:57:01     35.235
 2      2018-04-29 14:58:01     1237.3
 3      2018-04-29 14:58:01     4.68
 1      2018-04-29 14:58:01     123.578
 1      2018-04-29 14:59:01     1233.57
 3      2018-04-29 14:59:01     23.457
 2      2018-04-29 14:59:01     0.213
```

Id's with their dates (on insert current timestamp) are inserted every minute. Some ID's can be in the table for a period of time, and they can re-apepar later on at a different time. These id's are not ordered, they can be in any place of the current minute "batch".

From this table I'd like to extract the Values every 2 minute, so the output should be the following:

```
 ID     Date                    Value
 1      2018-04-29 14:51:01     0.1
 2      2018-04-29 14:51:01     0.21
 3      2018-04-29 14:51:01     0.123
 1      2018-04-29 14:53:01     1.23
 3      2018-04-29 14:53:01     7.9
 2      2018-04-29 14:53:01     1.68
 2      2018-04-29 14:55:01     2.3
 3      2018-04-29 14:55:01     3.4
 1      2018-04-29 14:55:01     5.7
 1      2018-04-29 14:57:01     12379.42
 2      2018-04-29 14:57:01     1230.1
 3      2018-04-29 14:57:01     35.235
```

**PD: I cannot use variables in this query but I can create functions / procedures as needed.**

As far as my little knowledge about MySQL goes... the easiest thing for me would be to create another table with a scheduled event that runs every two minutes and extracts the current values and inserts them in the new table.

Another problem with this query is that the 1 minute interval table has MILLIONS of rows with a lot of different ID's if it's to be done by only one query.

**So what would be best,** continue researching on how to build the query or create the tables with scheduled events?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I would have to post half my server program in order to expose all the queries, I think its clear what I'm asking for, just extract data every X minutes in a table of inserts every minute.

Comment: What if you have an ID that appears at 14:52, 14:54, 14:56, etc? Will it be completely excluded from your result?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, dropping those is not a problem, they often appear in a sequence of minutes, they do appear for a day at least every minute.

Comment: Will entries for the same ID always be exactly a minute apart, or is that a false implication of the same data? (i.e. could you have ID 6 at 2018-04-29 14:57:01, 2018-04-29 14:57:58, and 2018-04-29 14:58:59; the 2nd being < 1 minute from the first, and 3rd being more than one from the 2nd.

Comment: @Uueerdo they will be exactly 1 minute apart, this is done through an Scheduled event every minute, so all the dates will end in 01 second.

Comment: Then simply do not include rows with even minutes.IDs do not really matter.

Comment: @PM77-1 the "aim" is to be able to pick from a range of minutes, EG: show data every 2 minutes, or every 3, or every 4, 5 or 10.

Comment: OK. Then use `modulo` any way you want.

Comment: @PM77-1 lol... got it working with that, thanks. If you post an answer ill mark it at accepted. Didn't knew about the existance of mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL [`minute()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) function is the basis of your solution - it returns the *minute* part of the argument, [eg](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/32871):

```
minute('2018-04-29 14:51:01') -- returns 51
```

Use a mod division on that:

```
select ...
from ...
where minute(date) % 2 = 1  -- only odd minutes
```

similarly, every third minute would be:

```
where minute(date) % 3 = 1
```

and so on.

If you wanted to get more advanced, you could handpick the minutes after the hour you want, eg all prime minutes:

```
where minute(date) in (2,3,5,7,11,13,17,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59)
```

Comment: sometimes problems seem to be so complicated that I can't even think how a simple operator can solve it, thanks :)